# weblogic jaas server side example

Tags: java, weblogic, jaas

I need to implement JAAS authentication to lookup EJB beans in Weblogic from both client and server side.
For client this code works perfectly fine:

```
LoginContext loginContext = null;
loginContext = new LoginContext("Sample", new WeblogicCallbackHandler("weblogic", "PaSsWoRd", "localhost:7001"));
loginContext.login();

subject = loginContext.getSubject();
weblogic.security.Security.runAs(subject, new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object run() throws Exception {
        Object remote = iniCtx.lookup(SOME_BEAN_REF);
        Object home = PortableRemoteObject.narrow(remote, SOME_BEAN_HOME_CLASS);
        return homeClass.getMethod("create", new Class[] {}).invoke(home, new Object[] {});
    }
});
```

Now I need to do the same to lookup EJB from EJB.

But what URL should I use here?

Is it always "localhost:7001"?

And does it make sense to provide URL since I am definitely inside of Weblogic?